# GCP - GPU staging time reduction

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu, google-compute-engine, boot

I have an application that requires the smallest boot-time/TTL possible with GPUs attached to a VM in GCP CE. To keep cost down, my infrastructure is dependent on starting and stopping instances as demand increases/decreases.

I have achieved sub-5second start times with custom images without GPUs, but as soon as I attach a GPU, the time to "RUNNING" is always past 20-30s.

I have tried multiple different distros, clear linux, prepackaged Nvidia driver images, minimal installs of Fedora, minimalised Debian, reductions to kernel and userspace - systemd-analyze says my boot-time is 3s, but starting the VM with a GPU takes 20-30s in "STAGING" before running.

This *only* occurs when the gpu is attached to the VM and when removed the VM starts within the time mentioned by systemd-analyze. It is consistent across all distros and bootimages.

Is there any packages or documentation I am missing to speed up this staging-time with a GPU attached or is this a limitation with GCP's internal staging of GPU instances?

I'd much appreciate any help or advice.

If you're also experiencing this issue and would like to track its progress, I created a issue report:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/200575905

Answer (score 1):

This is an internal limitation in GCE and GKE, there's not a lot that can be currently done to remediate this.
However, I noticed that startup times have dropped over time, so there is some improvement in this matter.
You can report this via [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to follow development.

You can also consider using [Committed Use Discount](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts) or [Sustained Use Discounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/sustained-use-discounts). It may be beneficial in the long run to keep the instances running and therefore avoid the startup problem altogether.

Comment: Thanks Sergiusz, I'll keep this page updated if anything comes up.